# How to access mysql stored procedure out parameter in the nodejs code

Tags: node.js

call a mysql stored procedure with in and out parameter in the node js code

```
connection.query("call vts_active_tagid('"+RFIDNumber+"','"+Latitude+"','"+Longitude+"','"+datetime+"','"+imeno+"',@passengers,@trip)");
```

How to get the @passenger and @ trip value in the code

Comment: you can find the how-tos on tutorials also.

Comment: i want @ passenger and @trip values in the nodejs code

Comment: reading a output parameter of DB API in a language is basic think It could be found in Node.Js tutorial itself.This looks like simple what is what ?Search in the google if you get confusions on trying then ask what is the particular problem you were facing etc..

Comment: every article shows directly selecting using select query and no article is showing stored procedure with in and out parameter and also how to return the out parameter value in the nodejs code

Comment: simple google searching revealed a way try the below url https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/issues/682

Comment: got the answer,here is my code

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
db_ask.query(("SET @a = 0; CALL login('" + _userEmail + "','" + _password + "', @a); SELECT @a;"),function(err, results){
    //process result 
}
```

Assuming `_userEmail` and `_password` are parameters given in js function and `@a` is an int defined in stored procedure.

Comment: this is the perfect way to go if you want to have your application **vulnerable to sql injection**